# Using bazel to build tensorflow-serving from source meets error: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//…' failed (Exit 4)

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I'm attempting to use bazel to build tensorflow-serving from https://github.com/tensorflow/serving on CentOS 7.3. My gcc version is 4.8.5, bazel version is 0.10.1. I am sure that I followed the install introduction and I have set up all prerequisites requested. Every time I run the command :
bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/model_servers/... 
it will run for about 10~15 minutes and later stopped by an error:

```
ERROR:
/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/2d16d9349bff8cf3d8fc4a53d2a23056/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:3120:1: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:conv_ops' failed (Exit 4)
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
INFO: Elapsed time: 881.803s, Critical Path: 37.21s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

If I try another command :

```
bazel build -c opt tensorflow_serving/model_servers/...
```

to specifically build a subdirectory of serving, error comes like this:

```
ERROR: 
/home/serving/tensorflow_serving/batching/BUILD:122:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow_serving/batching:batching_util' failed (Exit 4)
tensorflow_serving/batching/batching_util.cc: In function 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> > tensorflow::serving::CalculateMaxDimSizes(const std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> > >&)':
tensorflow_serving/batching/batching_util.cc:165:34: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   for (int i = 0; i < batch.size(); ++i) {
                                  ^
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1486.641s, Critical Path: 211.94s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Please forgive my poor English and help me ... I have been stuck in this problem for quite a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar issue (349) on TensorFlow's Github, and it is very probable that you are running out of memory. They suggest adding the argument "--jobs 1 --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0" so that Bazel spawns no more than one compiler process at a time and limits system resource usage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! My total memory is 1.8G, and 1.5G is available. Memory is probabbly the problem but when I try the suggested argument, similar error comes again:                                                /home/lishu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_lishu/56f0d9f321642e225b60200b78f2552b/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:2502:1: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:svd_op' failed (Exit 4)
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
INFO: Elapsed time: 1276.437s, Critical Path: 87.89s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was away for a few days. If it's still relevant and you only have 1.5G, could you try "--local_resources 1024" instead?

Comment: yes, from 2048 to 1024, 512 and 256, I have tried several possible number but still face the same problem. I looked through tensorflow github issue and found couples of relating issue.  I am now desparate with my server and decide to change for a better one. And thank you for offering such a suggestion and the clue of github issue, where I should first search the issue !

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Your memory is not sufficient. Adding arguments --local_resource and --jobs actually does not help. Then I tried to use a google cloud instance with 4 cpus and 25G memory to build. I found that the build process may need 8G memory at a peak time. So your 1.8G memory is not sufficient.